# How to make a React form that would submit data as shown in example

Tags: reactjs, arrays, forms, object

How can I get the submitted data to look like this.

{
'banana': {
price: 2,
available: 5
}
};

Right now I just get an object. I want the name to act like the banana.

```
const [valueData, setValueData] = useState({
        name: "",
        des: "",
        alergens: "",
});



const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValueData({ ...valueData, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
};

const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
};


return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
            <label>Product name </label>
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Product name"
                name="name"
                value={valueData.name}
                onChange={handleChange}
            />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Product description </label>
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Product description"
                name="des"
                value={valueData.des}
                onChange={handleChange}
            />
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
)
```

I don't know what's the correct syntax for this problem.

Comment: Could you please explain where the `price` and `available` states are in your code?

Comment: Also, there is no `handleClick` handler in the snippet you have posted.